# Как заполнить контентом оставшееся место в блоке

Tags: html, css, flexbox

нужно расположить логотипы как на картинке. Не пойму как правильно св-ва раскинуть.. Если юзаю flex и ставлю строчное расположение - заполняется все только вниз, то есть место под кнопкой пустое, а список растет вниз. А если убираю строчное расположение - то снизу все ок, а вот область слева от текста и кнопка пустая[image: frame]